# jQuery sortable and nested lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a large list that I am trying to get so its sortable.

I would like the parent items `.cat-title` to be sortable between each other and this will move the children along with them. but then I would like the `.cat-title`'s children to be sortable between each `.cat-title`.

Its like categories and sub items but jQuery sortable just is not doing what I had expected it to do

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u46NZ/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="user-stream-list" class="user-stream-list">
    <li class="feed ui-sortable"><span class="cat-title" data-title="5">Apple</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="11" href="http://appleinsider.com/appleinsider.rss"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=appleinsider.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">AppleInsider</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="11" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="29" href="http://9to5mac.com/feed/"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=9to5mac.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">9to5Mac</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="29" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="feed ui-sortable"><span class="cat-title" data-title="15">Gadgets</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="2" href="http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.engadget.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">Engadget</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="2" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="59" href="http://feeds.gawker.com/gizmodo/vip"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.gawker.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">Gizmodo</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="59" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="feed ui-sortable"><span class="cat-title" data-title="9">Tech Crunch</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="60" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/gaming"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.feedburner.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">TechCrunch » Gaming</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="60" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="61" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/crunchgear"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.feedburner.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">TechCrunch » Gadgets</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="61" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="62" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Mobilecrunch"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.feedburner.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">TechCrunch » Mobile</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="62" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="43" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Techcrunch"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.feedburner.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">TechCrunch</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="43" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="feed ui-sortable"><span class="cat-title" data-title="9">Uncategorized</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="feed"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="8" href="http://feeds.gawker.com/lifehacker/full"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=lifehacker.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">Lifehacker</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="8" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
            <li class="feed"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="13" href="http://www.theverge.com/rss/index.xml"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.theverge.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">The Verge</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="13" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#user-stream-list > .feed" ).sortable();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is only trying to sort the all of the li's. Sortable needs to be called on each individual list (specifically the ul tag). This is what determines the boundaries of where things can be dragged. 
So give each list an id then just make them all sortable. (Look below)

```
<ul id="user-stream-list" class="user-stream-list">
<li class="feed ui-sortable "><span class="cat-title" data-title="5">Apple</span>
    <ul id="appleSub">
        <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="11" href="http://appleinsider.com/appleinsider.rss"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=appleinsider.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">AppleInsider</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="11" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="29" href="http://9to5mac.com/feed/"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=9to5mac.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">9to5Mac</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="29" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="feed ui-sortable"><span class="cat-title" data-title="15">Gadgets</span>
    <ul id="gadgetSub">
        <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="2" href="http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.engadget.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">Engadget</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="2" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="59" href="http://feeds.gawker.com/gizmodo/vip"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.gawker.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">Gizmodo</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="59" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="feed ui-sortable"><span class="cat-title" data-title="9">Tech Crunch</span>
    <ul id="techSub">
        <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="60" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/gaming"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.feedburner.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">TechCrunch » Gaming</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="60" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="61" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/crunchgear"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.feedburner.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">TechCrunch » Gadgets</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="61" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="62" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Mobilecrunch"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.feedburner.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">TechCrunch » Mobile</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="62" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="43" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Techcrunch"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=feeds.feedburner.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">TechCrunch</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="43" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="feed ui-sortable"><span class="cat-title" data-title="9">Uncategorized</span>
    <ul id="uncatSub">
        <li class="feed"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="8" href="http://feeds.gawker.com/lifehacker/full"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=lifehacker.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">Lifehacker</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="8" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="feed"><a data-uid="15" data-fid="13" href="http://www.theverge.com/rss/index.xml"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.theverge.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">The Verge</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="13" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#user-stream-list" ).sortable();
});
$(function() {
    $( "#appleSub" ).sortable();
});
$(function() {
    $( "#techSub" ).sortable();
});
$(function() {
    $( "#gadgetSub" ).sortable();
});
$(function() {
    $( "#uncatSub" ).sortable();
});
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/u46NZ/2/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to moving the sortable function to the `<li>` from the `<ul>` I had to add stopPropagation to the dragstart event in sortable. This allows for infinitely nested lists to work properly.

```
items.attr('draggable', 'true').on('dragstart.h5s', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // add this line to jquery.sortable.js
    .....
}
```

Then the lists need to all be "connected" when sortable() is called:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({ connectWith: '.sortable' });
```

Simply moving to the `<ul>` tags in my experience has only moved the top level list items even if a child is clicked.